# Not Found - 404 When trying to test passport oauth

Tags: php, laravel-5, oauth-2.0, restful-authentication, laravel-passport

I've created a new laravel 5.3 project and set it up from this tutorial : `https://mattstauffer.co/blog/introducing-laravel-passport`

but when I try to check the oauth server by sending restful request from http request add-on in firefox I get Not Found - 404

my request url : `http://localhost/pcheck/user` And I have set header : `"Application/json"`

My web.php Route file :

```
// First route that user visits on consumer app Route::get('/redirect', function () { // Build the query parameter string to pass auth information to our request $query = http_build_query([ 'client_id' => 3, 'redirect_uri' => 'http://localhost/pcheck/callback', 'response_type' => 'code', 'scope' => 'conference' ]);

// Redirect the user to the OAuth authorization page
return redirect('http://localhost/pcheck/oauth/authorize?' . $query);

});

// Route that user is forwarded back to after approving on server Route::get('/callback', function (Request $request) { $http = new GuzzleHttp\Client;

$response = $http->post('http://localhost/pcheck/oauth/token', [
    'form_params' => [
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
        'client_id' => '3',
        'client_secret' => 'azWM7CGS4UtIQ30sd5bwW5s53P52QjaRmUdWjKpx',
        'redirect_uri' => 'http://localhost/pcheck/callback',
        'code' => $request->code,
    ],
]);

return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);

});
```

My api.php Route file :

`Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) { return $request->user(); })->middleware('auth:api');`

I don't know where I'm wrong any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution my self. It's because of installing npm with sudo command, we have to install npm modules without sudo. So to fix this issue we should remove npm modules and then run npm install and wait until it install all needed dependecies.

FYI : You bootstrap.js file and package.json file should look like this :

Package.json :

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "prod": "gulp --production",
    "dev": "gulp watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "buble": "^0.14.0",
    "buble-loader": "^0.2.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "laravel-elixir": "^6.0.0-11",
    "laravel-elixir-vue-2": "^0.2.0",
    "laravel-elixir-webpack-official": "^1.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.16.2",
    "vue": "^2.0.1",
    "vue-loader": "^9.7.0",
    "vue-resource": "^1.0.3",
    "webpack": "^2.1.0-beta.22"
  }
}
```

Bootstrap.js :

```
window._ = require('lodash');

/**
 * We'll load jQuery and the Bootstrap jQuery plugin which provides support
 * for JavaScript based Bootstrap features such as modals and tabs. This
 * code may be modified to fit the specific needs of your application.
 */

window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
require('bootstrap-sass');

/**
 * Vue is a modern JavaScript library for building interactive web interfaces
 * using reactive data binding and reusable components. Vue's API is clean
 * and simple, leaving you to focus on building your next great project.
 */

window.Vue = require('vue');
require('vue-resource');

/**
 * We'll register a HTTP interceptor to attach the "CSRF" header to each of
 * the outgoing requests issued by this application. The CSRF middleware
 * included with Laravel will automatically verify the header's value.
 */

Vue.http.interceptors.push((request, next) => {
    request.headers.set('X-CSRF-TOKEN', Laravel.csrfToken);

    next();
});


Vue.http.options.credentials = true; //very important
/**
 * Echo exposes an expressive API for subscribing to channels and listening
 * for events that are broadcast by Laravel. Echo and event broadcasting
 * allows your team to easily build robust real-time web applications.
 */

// import Echo from "laravel-echo"

// window.Echo = new Echo({
//     broadcaster: 'pusher',
//     key: 'your-pusher-key'
// });
```

And another tip which is important you should use the latest npm version : 6.9.

Hope others problem solve quickly with this solution.